# How to make a rounded image with on side like a rounded triangle using svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to clip my image like below.

[image]

As you can see in above image the arrow is on the right side. I want the code such that it can be on either side left or right. Don't want arrow on both sides at the same time. Also I want the code to be generic. I mean I don't want it to be working for only specific size image.

I am trying from a long time but I am not very good with svg paths so I am failing.

Currently I have achieved the following.

```css
#image {
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVxru.jpg" alt="">
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M.0,.0 L0.7,.0 Q.8,.0 .83,.1 L.83,.1 .9,.48 C.905,.48 .905,.52 .9,.52 L.8,.9 Q.8,1 .9,1 Z">
            </path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I am unable to get the bottom corner rounded. And I don't know if I made the upper corner the correct. You can also see that the middle curve is not very smooth.

Kindly help me with this issue. If you want to use js you can use it too.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to compute an arrow-like path with rounded corners. The input data for path is: max-width (at arrow point), min-width (at top and bottom), height, direction (left or right), and corner radius. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would use css clip-path for the shape and SVG for the rounded edges:

```css
.image {
  display:inline-block;
  filter:url(#goo)
}
.image img {
  display:block;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% - 40px) 0,100% 50%,calc(100% - 40px) 100%,0 100%);
}

.image.left img {
  clip-path:polygon(40px 0,100% 0,100% 100%,40px 100%,0 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200">
</div>

<div class="image left">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200">
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>                                  <!-- adjust the the 10 here --v         -->
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton brother. Can you please explain a little how you did this.